# Replace default file name (Excel.xlsx) to the custom file name using GPV Interactive Report to MSExcel

Tags: oracle, plugins, oracle-apex

I want to Replace default file name (Excel.xlsx) to the custom file name using GPV Interactive Report to MSExcel (Plugin). The answer that I could find is "When not empty, the value from Report Attributes-> Filename field will be used." but this answer doesn't apply when the Plugin is used for a button. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

go to the report region affected by the plugin, under attributes theris a download tab and a filename field, put your desired name there:

[image]

Comment: Actually, I am disabling the download functionality of the report and creating an explicit download button to download. So this option is not available in my case.

Comment: Accordgin to the plugin documentation: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/glebovpavel/IR_to_MSExcel/master/Instructions.pdf the method I mentioned above is the way to do it, otherwise you can access the plugin source and modifiy the way it generates the file name